# how to implement file-upload using angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, file-upload

im trying to create a component in witch i implemented file upload function in a child component and then i'm trying to use that component's selector in an other one : 
my project structure is like that :

```
- upload : 
upload.component.html 
upload.component.ts
upload.module.ts
```

in this package i implemented this code :  upload.component.html :

```
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-12">


  <ngfFormData [files]="files" postName="file" [(FormData)]="sendableFormData"></ngfFormData>

  <ngfUploadStatus [(percent)]="progress" [httpEvent]="httpEvent"></ngfUploadStatus>


  <div class="inline-block">



  </div>

  <div>
    <h3>Drop Files</h3>
    <div class="border padding-15 border-radius bg-white mb-2">
      <div class="inline-block">
        <div ngfDrop [(validDrag)]="baseDropValid" (fileOver)="hasBaseDropZoneOver=$event" [(files)]="files" [accept]="accept" [maxSize]="maxSize"
          [(dragFiles)]="dragFiles" [(lastInvalids)]="lastInvalids" class="well my-drop-zone" [class.invalid-drag]="baseDropValid===false"
          [class.valid-drag]="baseDropValid" (filesChange)="lastFileAt=getDate()">
          <p class="font">Glisser/Déposer le document ou choisir un document...</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>




  </div>
  <div class="inline-block">
    <strong>maxSize in bytes</strong>
    <div>
      <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="maxSize" placeholder="1024 == 1mb" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="dragFiles">
    <h3 style="margin:0">Drag Files</h3>
    <p *ngIf="!dragFiles.length" style="color:red;">
      This browser does NOT release metadata for files being dragged. All files will be considered valid drags until dropped.
    </p>
    <pre>{{ dragFiles | json }}</pre>
  </div>

  <div class="bg-warning" *ngIf="lastInvalids?.length" style="margin-bottom: 40px">
    <h3 style="color:red;">Last {{ lastInvalids.length }} Invalid Selected Files</h3>

    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Error</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Size</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of lastInvalids;let i=index">
          <td>
            <div *ngIf="['image/gif','image/png','image/jpeg'].indexOf(item.file.type)>=0">
              <div class="previewIcon" [ngfBackground]="item.File"></div>
            </div>
            <strong>{{ item.file.name }}</strong>
          </td>
          <td nowrap>
            {{ item.type }}
          </td>
          <td nowrap>
            {{ item.file.type }}
          </td>
          <td nowrap>
            {{ item.file.size/1024/1024 | number:'.2' }} MB
          </td>
          <td nowrap>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" (click)="lastInvalids.splice(i,1)">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div style="margin-bottom: 40px">
    <h3>{{ files.length }} Queued Files</h3>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Size</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of files;let i=index">
          <td>
            <div *ngIf="['image/gif','image/png','image/jpeg'].indexOf(item.type)>=0">
              <div class="previewIcon" [ngfBackground]="item"></div>
            </div>
            <strong>{{ item.name }}</strong>
          </td>
          <td nowrap>
            {{ item.type }}
          </td>
          <td nowrap>
            {{ item.size/1024/1024 | number:'.2' }} MB
          </td>
          <td nowrap>

            <i class="icons icon-file_delete pointer" (click)="files.splice(i,1)"></i>

          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <div>
      <div>
        Queue progress:
        <div class="progress" style="">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': progress + '%' }"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <ng-container *ngIf="lastFileAt">
        <p>
          <strong>Last file(s) selected At:</strong> {{ lastFileAt | date : 'longTime' }}
        </p>
      </ng-container>

      <i *ngIf="progress==100" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>

      <button (click)="uploadFiles(files)" >
        Upload all
      </button>

      <button (click)="cancel()" >
        Cancel all
      </button>
      <button (click)="files.length=0" >
        Remove all
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

upload.component.ts :

```
  import { Component, OnInit, NgModule  } from '@angular/core';
  import { ngfModule, ngf } from "angular-file";
  import {
  HttpClient, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpEvent
 } from "@angular/common/http";
 import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
 import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

  @Component({
  selector: 'sof-upload',
   templateUrl: './upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload.component.scss']
   })
 export class UploadComponent implements OnInit {
 accept = '*'
 files:File[] = []
 progress:number
 url = 'https://evening-anchorage-3159.herokuapp.com/api/'
 hasBaseDropZoneOver:boolean = false
 httpEmitter:Subscription
 httpEvent:HttpEvent<{}>
 lastFileAt:Date

  sendableFormData:FormData//populated via ngfFormData directive
   constructor(public HttpClient:HttpClient) { }

   cancel(){
  this.progress = 0
  if( this.httpEmitter ){
  console.log('cancelled')
  this.httpEmitter.unsubscribe()
  }
  }

  uploadFiles(files:File[]):Subscription{
  const req = new HttpRequest<FormData>('POST', this.url, 
 this.sendableFormData, {
    reportProgress: true//, responseType: 'text'
  })

  return this.httpEmitter = this.HttpClient.request(req)
.subscribe(
  event=>{
    this.httpEvent = event

    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
      delete this.httpEmitter
      console.log('request done', event)
      }
     },
   error=>console.log('Error Uploading',error)
    )
   }

   getDate(){
   return new Date()
   }
   ngOnInit() {

  }



   }
```

upload.module.ts:

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
 import { UploadComponent } from './upload.component';

 @NgModule({
 imports: [
    CommonModule,

    ],
   declarations: [UploadComponent],
   providers: [],
   exports: [UploadComponent]
     })
  export class UploadModule { }
```

then i tried to call its selector in an other component so i just created the component and added :

```
<sof-upload></sof-upload>
```

i added the first component module in my app.module.ts 
 but im getting this error that i couldn't solve :

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'files' since it isn't a known property of 'ngfFormData'. ("


  <ngfFormData [ERROR ->][files]="files" postName="file" [(FormData)]="sendableFormData"></ngfFormData>

  <ngfUploadS"): ng:///UploadModule/UploadComponent.html@4:19
Can't bind to 'FormData' since it isn't a known property of 'ngfFormData'. ("


  <ngfFormData [files]="files" postName="file" [ERROR ->][(FormData)]="sendableFormData"></ngfFormData>

  <ngfUploadStatus [(percent)]="progress" [ht"): ng:///UploadModule/UploadComponent.html@4:51
'ngfFormData' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngfFormData' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("


  [ERROR ->]<ngfFormData [files]="files" postName="file" [(FormData)]="sendableFormData"></ngfFormData>

"): ng:///UploadModule/UploadComponent.html@4:6
Can't bind to 'percent' since it isn't a known property of 'ngfUploadStatus'. ("="files" postName="file" [(FormData)]="sendableFormData"></ngfFormData>

  <ngfUploadStatus [ERROR ->][(percent)]="progress" [httpEvent]="httpEvent"></ngfUploadStatus>
```

Comment: What version of angular are you using? If its Angular 5 then the library seems to have some problems related to the upgrade. You might need to downgrade to Angular 4.

Comment: Did you correctly add `ngfModule` to the imports of your main Angular module? As shown [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file#uploading) you need to import the module in `UploadModule` imports to have it working.

Comment: that works thanks. It was about adding ngfModule to the imports of the child module.

Answer (score 0):

just solved that by adding ngfModule to the imports of the child module. Great example to use so enjoy trying it.